# Orientdb fulltext lucene index on embeddedmap values

Tags: indexing, lucene, orientdb

I am using OriendDb community 2.1.13.

I have a vertex of class `Area` with a field `names` that is of type *embeddedmap* with linked type *String*.

Is possibile (and how) to create an index on the values of the embeddedmap `names` to create queries like

```
select Area where names.en LUCENE 'Italy'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such deep level of indexing is not supported, yet.

Comment: for what you know it is planned in a future release of OrientDb?